# Not able to create hibernate XML Mapping file in eclipse

Tags: mysql, eclipse, postgresql, hibernate

I am very new to hibernate, 
I am trying to create the Hibernate XML mapping file, but after choosing the class that I want to work with in the wizard, I get the following message in the wizard.

> "the refactoring does not change any source code."

I understand that I can write the XML file on without the help of the wizard, but I am worried that I might have a different problem which is causing this. I also had the same problem previously when I was working with Postgres, after when I was not able to find a solution I thought that I would use MySQL, but I still have the same problem. any idea what is causing this ?

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class Exchange {
private int en_id;
private int identifier;
private String ng_id;

@Id

Then the setters and getters
```

I am using eclipse oxygen, XAMPP 5.6.32 , phpMyAdmin 4.7.4 on MAC

Comment: It would be better if you can show your code and your researches before asking the question.

Comment: Hey Mayur, I don't believe that this is a code related problem, I am getting this message in the wizard itself

Comment: you are trying to create a xml file, can you show the file

Comment: Please, write `XML` file without a wizard and will tell us what happens.

Comment: @v.ladynev I need to know why the wizard is not working, I am currently working on a smaller table, but later on I will have to work on the other tables and I would like to get the wizard working for that task

Comment: Why do you need XML mapping? There are annotations in your code, continue using them.